# How can I associate custom Data with any sent message through Smooch SDK?

Tags: ios, swift, smooch

I want to enquire how can I send custom data associated with the messages sent through Smooch SDK such as User Id or User Email.

Comment: Missing detail. Please provide examples of what you have tried, sample code etc.

Answer (score 1):

Many Smooch objects including appUsers and messages have an optional [metadata](https://docs.smooch.io/guide/using-metadata/#using-metadata) JSON property that you can use for this purpose. Note carefully that there are limits on data types allowed in metadata, and on the overall size.

You can include custom message metadata as part of a [Post message](https://docs.smooch.io/rest/#post-message) API call for example, or via any the supported API wrapper libraries.

Comment: any code example of how to send custom meta-data with every to smooch via smooch chat widget in iOS (swift)

Comment: https://docs.smooch.io/api/ios/Classes/SKTUser.html#//api/name/addProperties:
https://docs.smooch.io/api/ios/Classes/SKTMessage.html#//api/name/metadata